# Laravel: if user wasRecentlyCreated top up balance

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My developer left , so I need to finish our project by myself.

I'was doing Automation using C# so, have some knowledge in coding.

Question is:
How correctly top up new user's balance?

- I have in SQL table - users, where all users are stored. (user_id +
  name/surname + reg date)
- I have in SQL table user_balance, where all    users with balance are
  stored (user_id + balance ammount)

So, I need to somehow gift to a new user some money.

Do I need to work with blade view, and trying something with

```
@if user reg date == bla bla
sql query
@else
ignore
@endif
```

or, better to create with controllers, models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from another similar answer, you need to use events, when  the user is created

Inside your User's model, you can create an event handlers like so:

```
/**
 * The event map for the model.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $dispatchesEvents = [
    'created' => \App\Events\UserCreatedEvent::class,
];
```

Then you can create an event like so:

**UserCreatedEvent**

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;

class UserCreatedEvent
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
    }
}
```

Then you can create a listener to create the balance:

**UserCreatedListener**

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Events\UserCreatedEvent;

class UserCreatedListener
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param UserCreatedEvent $event
     */
    public function handle(UserCreatedEvent $event)
    {
        // update their balanace here
        $event->user->update(['balance' => 1000]);
    }
}
```

Then inside your eventserviceprovider.php add

```
/**
 * The event listener mappings for the application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\UserCreatedEvent' => [
        'App\Listeners\UserCreatedListener',
    ],
];
```

Comment: thnx, it helped!

Comment: @P.Pjotrs please don't forget to mark an answer that helped.

Answer (score 1):

As @Nate points out, model events will get you what you need, howver, I'd use the `Creating` event rather than `Created` as then you can set the balance as the record is saved, saving you the update query.

You definitely do not want to do this in the blade view. Try to keep all business logic out of view files and contained within controllers/models/event listeners, etc.

You can simplify this from the other answer by adding the event handling within the model's static boot method.

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function($model)
    {
         $model->balance = 100;
    });
}
```

Comment: thnx, it helped!